# custom mysql function in nodejs returns undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

so I have a multi function in a file in NodeJS, and it returns undefined, so here is my code:
`

```
var MySql = require('mysql');

var mysql = MySql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_IP,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: "gamezone_3tar"
});

mysql.connect(function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('MySql Connection Successfully!');
});

module.exports = {
    checkGuild: function(gid){
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM GUILDS WHERE `gid` = '"+gid+"'";
        mysql.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return true;
        });
    },
    addGuild: function(gid, gname, gowner){
        var sql = "INSERT INTO GUILDS(`gid`, `gname`, `gOwner`) VALUES ('"+gid+"', '"+gname+"', '"+gowner+"')";
        mysql.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            return true;
        });
    },
    checkVip: function(type, id){
        if(type == 'guild')
            var sql = 'SELECT vip FROM GUILDS WHERE `gid` = ?';
        else if(type == 'user')
            var sql = 'SELECT vip FROM USERS WHERE `uid` = ?';
        
        mysql.query(sql, [id], function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            var tempdata = JSON.parse(result);
            if(tempdata.vip == 'false') 
                return false;
            else if(tempdata.vip == 'true') 
                return true;
        });
    },
    addVip: function(type, id){
        if(type == 'guild')
            var sql = "UPDATE GUILDS SET vip = 'true' WHERE `gid` = '"+id+"'";
        else if(type == 'user')
            var sql = "UPDATE USERS SET vip = 'true' WHERE `uid` = '"+id+"'";
        
        mysql.query(sql, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            return true;
        });
    },
    removeVip: function(type, id){
        if(type == 'guild')
            var sql = "UPDATE GUILDS SET vip = 'false' WHERE `gid` = '"+id+"'";
        else if(type == 'user')
            var sql = "UPDATE USERS SET vip = 'false' WHERE `uid` = '"+id+"'";
        
        mysql.query(sql, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            return true;
        });
    },
    removeGuild: function(gid){
        var sql = "DELETE FROM GUILDS WHERE `gid` = '"+gid+"'";
        mysql.query(sql, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            return true;
        });
    }
};
```

and here is the discord bot command i use to trigger this functions:

```
var db = require('../../etc/database.js');

module.exports = {
  name: "addvip",
  description: "change guild to vip",
  execute(message) {
    const msgID = message.author.id;
    if (!admins.includes(msgID)) return;
    if(db.checkGuild(message.guild.id) == true)
    {
      if(db.checkVip('guild', message.guild.id) == true)
      {
        console.log('already vip!');
      }
      else if(db.checkVip('guild', message.guild.id) == false)
      {

        if(db.addVip('guild', message.guild.id) == true)
        {
          console.log('Guild is now vip!');
        }else{
          console.log('error in addvip');
        }

      }else{
        console.log('error in checkVip');
      }
    }
    else if(!db.checkGuild(message.guild.id) == true)
    {
      if(db.addGuild(message.guild.id, message.guild.name, message.guild.owner) == true)
      {
        if(db.addVip('guild', message.guild.id) == true)
        {
          console.log('added to vip!');
        }else console.log('error in adding [check]');
      }else console.log(db.addGuild(message.guild.id, message.guild.name, message.guild.owner));
    }else console.log('wtf!');
  }
};
```

so any idea how to fix this, please? I'm seriously working on this code like 1 month after solving SQL errors and ...

and BTW, it successfully connects to MySQL server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be due to the fact that your SQL code uses callbacks, so no data is immediately returned and therefore, the return value is `undefined`. To fix this, you need to make the SQL functions return a `Promise` and change the `return` statement to `resolve()`, like this:

```js
checkGuild: function(gid){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM GUILDS WHERE `gid` = '"+gid+"'";
        mysql.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
},
```

Then, you need to use `await` wherever the function is called in order to wait for the `Promise` to complete. Since, you are calling the functions in the `addvip` command file, you need to make the `execute` function asynchronous, so that you can use `await`:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "addvip",
  description: "change guild to vip",
  async execute(message) {
    const msgID = message.author.id;
    if (!admins.includes(msgID)) return;
    if(await db.checkGuild(message.guild.id) == true)
```

Comment: so i got this error:
`
/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437

throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: @EhsanFox The error looks like there is a problem with your SQL queries or the file you are accessing. Did you remember to apply the examples in my answer to all parts of your code?

Comment: i applied all of them, so can u tell mewhat is wrong with my sql query?

here is the code:

`mysql.query(sql, [id], function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    var tempdata = JSON.parse(result);
    if(tempdata.vip == 'false') 
     resolve(false);
    else if(tempdata.vip == 'true') 
     resolve(true);
   });`

Comment: @EhsanFox You didn't make it return a `Promise` like in my answer.

Comment: i did as you said, the undefined think is gone, and instead of that, im getting the error that i sent

Comment: Please put your modified code and error message on [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/) and post a link here.

Comment: this is the command file: https://hastebin.com/ejabumiwov.js

and this is the db module file: https://hastebin.com/robugehoxo.js

Comment: @EhsanFox For the command file, you forgot `await` inside the second to last `console.log()`.

Comment: @EhsanFox I have done some research and it seems that you must have a malformed JSON file. The error has nothing to do with MySQL, it's just rethrown by mySQL.

Comment: @EhsanFox I think the issue is in the `checkVip()` function. You are attempting to use `JSON.parse()` on the result of the SQL query, but the result might not be JSON. Log it and see what value it is.

Comment: i changed the `result.vip` to `result[0].vip` it worked for awhile, i tried it on another database it said this error: /app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437

throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'vip' of undefined

Comment: I don't know what `result` is, so I can't help.